# How to make the Google maps API floating panels responsive?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, responsive

An image of the map on a mobile:
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFPo8.png)

I have tried the following Css and HTML but I couldn't make the floating panels show when the map is used on a mobile. Is there anything I can change in the CSS or html to make the floating panels responsive please ?

```css
#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter an origin location">

    <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a destination location">

    <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
      <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
      <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
      <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
    </div>
     </div>

    <div id="right-panel"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="map"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you asking here; for floating panels you mean the `origin-input` and `destination-input` ids?

Comment: yes. When i do it in a mobile form they hide instead of going under each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, first add `display: flex` to the outer container like this:

```
#content {
display: flex;
flex-flow: wrap;
flex-direction: row; 
}
```

this creates an outer wrapper for your "floating panels" and make the inner content responsive to changes in view-ports.

Then add a media query specifically for the mobile viewers you are targeting. This is an example:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 500px){
   #content {
    flex-direction: columnn; 
   }
 }
```

[Proof of concept here in this BIN](https://jsbin.com/fayogep/1/edit?html,css,output)

Just resize the output window to see the effect.

Comment: What do you mean _it did not work_? If you **check my bin** in the above link, the view is responsive. When you resize the output window you see changes in the view, cannot you see those?

Comment: ohhh ok sry didn't see it (still new at this) thank you :)

Comment: OK, glad that it helped. **Accept my answer** as valid then please